# Load local html in webview depending on language

Tags: android, html, webview

Hy... I have a webview component loading a local html file under asset folder, working perfect.

Now I want to translate mi app, and I need the webview to load the translated html file depending on the phone language.

How can I do that?

Thanks a lot !!!!

my code...

```
package com.altaguia.difuntos;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.RenderPriority;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class AcercadeActivity extends Activity {



    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.acercade);

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        myWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
        myWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/acercade.html");

    }

    public void backBTN(View v)
    {
        finish();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Locale` to find the device language, then load the appropriate html file:

```
String lang = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
String filename = "acercade.html";
if (lang.equals("fr")) {
  filename = "acercade.fr.html";
}
myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/" + filename);
```

Comment: The point is that getLanguage() can return an empty string. Even if manging this case,this might drive to the wrong html file. So in this case, I would suggest rather using getISO3Language ().

Answer (score 0):

Use php.
Select language and pass it as a parameter in either GET or POST.
Pass it to the php file. In php file create a conditional include.

```
if ( $_GET['language']=="EN") include "indexEN.php";
else include index.php;
```

Plase the translation in specific files and include them upon verification in the condition.
If you will have many translations then use Switch/Case instead of IF.

If you will use GET form, then URL will look like this:

```
www.webpage.com/index.php?language=EN
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I am so new in android and programing that I don't understand your solution. Could you please explain it to me as if I were stupid? lol.....

I posted my code...

thanks a lot !!!

Comment: Yes. Now you posted your code and now it's obvious the Q is about android. Your tags and initial description did not mentioned that fact at all.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I didn't realized that. Thanks anyway.